# logging into angular fullstack default app using google oauth2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-fullstack

I have angular fullstack running on localhost:9000

I want to be able to login by clicking the Connect with Google+ button on login page.
It does not work and I keep getting error 400. Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

I have been to Google developers console and set up a Project

I have set the following in the Google Developers Console

Client ID             `<Client ID>`

Client Secret         `<Client Secret>`

Redirect URIs         http://localhost:9000/auth/google/oauth2callback

Javascript Origins    http://localhost:9000

In the local.env.js

GOOGLE_ID: `<Client ID>`

GOOGLE_SECRET: `<Client Secret>`

When I go to login by clicking the Connect with google+ button I get error 400.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or can explain to me how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own problem.

I altered the Redirect URI in the Google Developers Console.

so that is the following:

Redirect URIs http://localhost:9000/auth/google/callback